# How to prevent two doors from opening into each other?

Tags: doors, hardware

I have pantry cabinet door that abuts the door to a half-bath. They meet at a 90° angle and are hinged at the same side:

[image: Top-down view of the doors]

Right now, I have a hinge pin doorstop on the half bath door.  Temporarily I have it taped to the half bath door so it rotates along with the door.  If the half bath door opens fully, then the hinge pin doorstop contacts the wall between the hinges of the two doors.  If the pantry door opens when the half bath door is closed, the hinge pin doorstop catches the pantry door before the two doors hit.

Part of the reason why I needed to tape the hinge pin doorstop to the half bath door was because its pads are at 90° to each other.  If there existed a hinge pin doorstop with the pads at 180° from each other (so it looks like a "T", with the base of the T attaching to the hinge and a pad at either end of the top of the T), I think that would solve my problem.

**Does such a doorstop exist?  Is there a better way?**

**Edit:**

Here is a picture of the doors:

[image: Picture of the doors]

Here is a closeup when the bathroom door is open, with the hinge pin doorstop hitting the wall:

[image: Bathroom door open]

And a closeup when the pantry door is opened:

[image: Pantry door opened]

With this current setup, the pantry door can open at most about 45°, which is sufficient, and the bathroom door can open to a full 90°.  Under no circumstances can the two doors touch.

Comment: Is there any chance of reversing that half bath door around so that it opens inward instead of outward?

Comment: Unfortunately not; it is a very small bathroom.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you saying that what you've currently got is good except for the need to tape it to your door? What would happen if it were spinning free?

Comment: Yes, the current solution works, but it is ugly.  I'm ideally looking for a solution that will prevent both doors from touching each other regardless of their positions.  If both doors were spinning free, the handle of the pantry door could strike the glass of the bathroom door, potentially shattering it.  The handle of the bathroom door could also potentially scratch the pantry door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your excellent diagram, I think these may be your ticket.  They are designed for your very problem.

Disclaimer: I've never bought anything from the site in the link and I'm not endorsing them.

[The Stoppa](https://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfmhttps://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfm?id=660428)

[image: The Stoppa]

Comment: I forgot to mention: the pantry is a cabinet, not a room.  So the pantry door does not have a regular door hinge.

Comment: I don't follow.  I thought you were looking for an alternative for the bathroom door.

Comment: I edited the question to include more pictures.  This will prevent the bathroom door from hitting the pantry door, but it won't prevent the pantry door from hitting the bathroom door.  I guess I could solve that by adding some sort of bump stop in the wall above the bathroom door, since the pantry door is taller…

Comment: I agree on the bump stop over the bathroom door.